# Observable Stream to Many Filtered Subscriptions

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular8

I am writing a service for an API called multisubscribe that takes an array of variables and starts sending a stream of data over HTTP. The data is a JSON payload with variable data sent upon change.

`{device: "OEE", variable: "Availability", data: [12]}`

I've managed to parse the stream and create an observable that emits these JSON payloads, when unsubscribing the HTTP request is aborted. Perfect! [You can see the code on GitHub](https://github.com/astone2014/devicewise-angular/blob/master/projects/devicewise-angular/src/lib/devicewise-multisubscribe-new.service.ts).

---

Now I'm trying to abstract the observable into another service called the MultisubscribeStore. I basically want to be able to add, remove, edit variables and each time the unsubscribe, resubscribe happens automatically within the service. This way the user doesn't have to think about the single stream.

I tried creating a separate subject and emitting on that subject but I couldn't determine when the subject was done, so I couldn't unsubscribe.

---

I also want to be able to filter the stream into many streams and pass them down to child components. For example I have 5 gauge components and they each represent different data. How can I send down an observable to each of them that will only emit the values they're interested in. I feel like creating multiple new observables with filter is poor performance.

```
const subscription1 = multiSubscribe$.pipe(
  filter((data) => data.variable === 'Availability')
);

const subscription2 = multiSubscribe$.pipe(
  filter((data) => data.variable === 'Quality')
);

const subscription3 = multiSubscribe$.pipe(
  filter((data) => data.variable === 'Performance')
);
```

Maybe what I want is already built into RXJS. I tried playing with share and multicast but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a single stream you need to filter the events and keep only the ones a specific gauge needs at some point anyway.

A similar scenario can be found in ngrx, where we have a stream of actions, and effects are listening to this stream and filtering only the actions they are interested in (using `ofType("MyAction")` operator, which simply does `.filter(action => action.type === "MyAction")` under the hood). I'm afraid there's no other way